# Angular/Typescript syntax error?

Tags: angular, typescript

So right now im writing a login system with angular and firestore, here's my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';


interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  photoURL?: string;
  displayName?: string;
  favouriteColor?: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private afs: AngularFirestore,
              private router: Router) {
                this.user = this.afAuth.authState
                  .switchMap(user => {
                    if(user) {
                      return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
                    } else {
                      return Observable.of(null)
                    }
                  })
               }

}

googleLogin(){
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
  return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
}


private oAuthLogin(provider){
  return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((credential) => {
      this.updateUserData(credential.user)
    })
}

private updateUserData(user){
  const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.id}`)

  const data: User = {
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    displayName: user.displayName,
    photoURL: user.photoURL
  }

  return userRef.set(data)
}
```

However, my console log is telling me, that i miss semicolons, not quite sure why:

```
ERROR in src/app/core/auth.service.ts(40,14): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/app/core/auth.service.ts(46,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
src/app/core/auth.service.ts(46,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/app/core/auth.service.ts(53,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
src/app/core/auth.service.ts(53,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

and also:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/core/auth.service.ts
Module parse failed: 'return' outside of function (48:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|     var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
|     return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
| }
| oAuthLogin(provider);
```

I have obviously no idea what typescript wants to tell me. For example, in the first error, typescript says i need to add an semicolon at line 40, but line 40 is the function googleLogin(){} itself, so not quite sure whats going on here.

If anyone is able to find the misspell / error i would appreciate it. Been sitting on this for now over an hour and simply can't find whats exactly wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the second error, about the 'return', you have closed the class and you have the next 3 functions outside of the class, you need to move those 3 functions inside the class

Comment: I think your constructor has one curly bracket more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is fixed code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';


interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  photoURL?: string;
  displayName?: string;
  favouriteColor?: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private afs: AngularFirestore,
              private router: Router) {
                this.user = this.afAuth.authState
                  .switchMap(user => {
                    if(user) {
                      return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
                    } else {
                      return Observable.of(null)
                    }
                  })
               }

// HERE U HAD BRACKET THAT DIDNT SUPPOSED TO BE HERE - it ended class

googleLogin(){
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
  return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
}


private oAuthLogin(provider){
  return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((credential) => {
      this.updateUserData(credential.user)
    })
}

private updateUserData(user){
  const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.id}`)

  const data: User = {
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    displayName: user.displayName,
    photoURL: user.photoURL
  }

  return userRef.set(data)
}
} // This bracked you miss
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjqmlv

Comment: yeah I think we covered that in comments ;)

Answer (score 0):

So turns out (thanks to Kalamarico and Mirko Acimovic) that i missed a bracket at the bottom. I added it and replaced 1 more at the top. 
But there was one more problem (See bottom)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';


interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  photoURL?: string;
  displayName?: string;
  favouriteColor?: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private afs: AngularFirestore,
              private router: Router) {
                this.user = this.afAuth.authState
                  .switchMap(user => {
                    if(user) {
                      return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
                    } else {
                      return Observable.of(null)
                    }
                  })

                }


googleLogin(){
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
  return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
}


private oAuthLogin(provider){
  return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((credential) => {
      this.updateUserData(credential.user)
    })
}

private updateUserData(user){
  const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.id}`)

  const data: User = {
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    displayName: user.displayName,
    photoURL: user.photoURL
  }

  return userRef.set(data)
}


}
```

After i added the bracket, my terminal log said:

```
ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(10,22): error TS2420: Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface 'FirebaseApp'.
  Property 'automaticDataCollectionEnabled' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'.
```

I simply ran `npm update` in this fixed the issue. App is now working! Thanks everyone!